# gitlab continuous deployment private key security

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I am working on a php project.

I have 2 servers:

```
- gitlab server
- production server (apache2 + php + mysql)
```

My PHP source files are stored and versioned on my gitlab server.
I want to automatically deploy php files to production server.

Here is what i have done:
- I have created a "deployer" user on production server.
- I have ran ssh-keygen for this user.
- I have copy and paste ssh private key (/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa) into a gitlab secret variable.

Here is an extract of .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  only:
  - master
  script:
  - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > id_rsa
  - chmod go-rwx ./id_rsa
  - rsync -hrvz --delete --exclude '.git*' --exclude id_rsa -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./id_rsa' ./ deployer@productionservrer.com:/var/www/html
```

Everything works.

My problem is a need to create a temporarily id_rsa file to store private key for rsync. This file is exclude from rsync but i am upset about this file. If someone accidentally remove rsync --exclude options, my id_rsa file will be exposed on webserver.

So my question is how can i work without having to store private key in a temp file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to create id_rsa file in same folder as is your project at? If you simply move id_rsa file prom project folder to, say, /home/local-user/.ssh folder you won’t have to worry about accidental copy? Sorry for typos, writing from phone...

Comment: That is true, but, if somebody compromises your gitlab server to the point that can read 600 files of other users you are in far worse situation, since that someone can backup full gitlab and your code or secrets are no longer secrets... As I've understood your original concern was not to accidentally leak id_rsa to prod server, this is different topic, and broad one (from security standpoint, and highly dependent on gitlab runners you are using also)...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What do you do in your projects ?

Comment: This is topical, but in a nutshell we are using Kubernetes runners. In gitlab we are also keeping secrets related to deployment to clusters but their instances are ephemeral to runners and gone when runners finish deploying and terminate (so not worrying of leaving stuff on gitlab server). I believe docker runners would give you similar behavior. We have two phases, each with own runner - first is build from project folder (that result in docker image being pushed to docker registry) and then deploy (deploys built image to same or different kubernetes cluster, depending on branch).

Comment: In fact i think there is a security hole, even if id_rsa file is in another folder. This file is owned by gitlab-runner user. All projects have this same user. So it is possible for another user to create a script in his .gitlab-ci.yml that will fetch my id_rsa file...